# How to filter images by category using input form and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, image, input, filter

For example

I have a page where there are 4 images

```
<img src="1" />

<img src="2" />

<img src="3" />

<img src="4" />

Filter:
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="gallery" value="abstract" /> Abstract<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gallery" value="landscape" /> Landscape
</form>
```

How can I add some markup each image to be part of a certain category, then using a checkbox to filter them with `jquery .hide()`? I'd prefer not using the class attribute.
Thanks a lot for the huge help!

Comment: `I'd prefer not using the class attribute.` Why not?

Comment: So, like, image 1 and 4 might be of the landscape category and 2 and 3 might be abstract?

Comment: You could use the image width and height to determine their orientation.. orientation = ( width > height ) ? 'landscape' : 'abstract'..

Comment: @Johan, dude, that's brilliant. Put that in an answer.

Comment: I'd prefer not using the class attribute because I'll be using it in css for all images.

Comment: @Johan.... those arent types of orientation...

Comment: @Grozav -- so? why can't you use classes? you dont have to put those classes into the css...

Comment: I have a feeling that he may use the classes for styling pictures and doesn't want to tie that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For type add a certain class (even if you do not want to...)

```
$('input[value="landscape"]').click(function(){
    $('.landClass').toggle();
});

$('input[value="abstract"]').click(function(){
    $('.absClass').toggle();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3bk22/

Comment: Didn't you say you'd prefer not to use a class attribute?!

Comment: @Steve but there is no better way ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="abstract">
   <img src="1" />

   <img src="2" />
</div>

<div id="landscape">
   <img src="3" />

   <img src="4" />
</div>

$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
  $("#abstract, #landscape").hide();
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
     $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: That is assuming that images **are not** all mixed up.

Comment: Yes, the question said to add the required markup without adding any class attributes.

Comment: Neal, What is wrong in my answer except for arranging the images in a div container?

Comment: You mean we should never wrap images in a div tag?

Comment: No. your answer does **not** answer the question correctly. i did not dv you. I am just letting you know.

Comment: Also in your version both will never be shown at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the attribute alt of img

```
<img src="1" alt="abstract"/>
```

and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="abstract"]').click(function(){
       $('img[alt="abstract"]').toggle();
})

     $('input[name="landscape"]').click(function(){
       $('img[alt="abstract"]').toggle();
})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/shaneburgess/wTkR5/6/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#abstractCheck").change(function(){
       $(".abstract").toggle();
    });

     $("#landScapeCheck").change(function(){
       $(".landscape").toggle();
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
   <span class="abstract">
    <img src="1"/>
</span>

<span class="landscape">
   <img src="2" />
</span>

<span class="abstract">
   <img src="3" />
</span>

<span class="landscape">
   <img src="4" />
</span>
```

Comment: your fiddle does not match your answer at all

Comment: ? whats with the change to the DOM?

Comment: @grozav wants to avoid using image classes.

Comment: I meant image classes (Updated my last answer), I am not sure that span classes are not wanted.