# How to filter images by .class using drop down box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I was looking around at another question 
[How to filter images by category using input form and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792616/how-to-filter-images-by-category-using-input-form-and-jquery)

Its sorta like my question and I tried playing around with some of the jsfiddles however I had no success.
http://jsfiddle.net/3bk22/44/

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/123x100/123/1" class='landClass' />

<img src="http://placehold.it/100/fe2/2" class='landClass' />

<img src="http://placehold.it/100x50/aaa/3" class='absClass' />

<img src="http://placehold.it/200x150/42E/4" class='landClass' />
<br/> <br/>
Filter: <br/>
<select>
<option value="abstract" /> Abstract<br />
<option value="landscape" /> Landscape<br />
</select>

$('option[value="landscape"]').click(function(){
$('.landClass').toggle();
 });

$('option[value="abstract"]').click(function(){
    $('.absClass').toggle();
});
```

I basically wan't to know if I can create a filter for 850+ images after they are given a class. I was going to use the checkbox, however there will be 50+ categories and I was hoping to minimize the area required for the box.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
- A drop down filter for all categories. 
- A drop down menu that I can add unlimited categories to.
- A default on load which displays the box empty.
- Hiding any image that isn't apart of the current filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either tweak your class names or your dropdown, to be consistent, and then do this:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $("img").hide();
    $("." + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bk22/45/

Comment: So using that code would accept anything I set as an option as long as the value="..." is the same as a class="..." correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would use data attributes to reference corresponding images:

```
var $img = $('.landClass, .absClass');
$('.filter').change(function() {
    $img.hide().filter('.' + $('option:selected', this).data('class')).show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<option value="abstract" data-class="absClass">Abstract</option>
<option value="landscape" data-class="landClass">Landscape</option>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bk22/47/

Or probably better idea just to change class names of the images to match option values like James Montagne suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('img').hide();
    if(value == 'abstract'){
        $('.absClass').show();
    } else if(value == 'landscape'){
         $('.landClass').show();
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HAhCP/1/)

Comment: **Question:** Would doing this require me to add every single category into my jquery? Or is it possible to add something into the jquery that would search for all possible options? *Thanks for your answer though works a treat!*

Comment: @KennenLasuni it depends if you can change the value of the options then you can simplify this much more